# Singularity of $h(z)=f(z)g(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ and $g$ be non constant and holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$. Where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk.
>   Define $h(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ such that
>   $h(z)=f(z)g(z)$.
>
> 1. Explain why $h$ has an isolated singularity at $z=0$.
> 2. Discuss the nature of the isolated singularity $z=0$ for $h$ (When is it Removable? Pole? an essential singularity?)

**My Answer**
 1. It is isolated because both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$. Hence $h$ is also holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$.
2. I can see that if $f$ and $g$ are bounded on $\mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ tso does $h$. Thus it has a removable singularity if both $f$ and $g$ has a removable singularity. BUT this is not an iff condition for example $f=z$ and $g=1/z$

Now when it comes to a pole, if both $f$ and $g$ has a pole it says that $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}f(z)=\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}g(z)=\infty$. Hence we can show that $\lim\limits_{z\to 0}h(z)=\infty$.  That is a pole at $h$.

But non of those conditions are if and only if conditions. So how can I obtain the essential singularity ? and also is there any better way of explaining them.

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 cases to check :

- both $f,g$ are meromorphic at $0$
- one of them has an essential singularity
- both have an essential singularity (don't expect a simple criterion for thisone, see $f(z)=e^{1/z},g(z)=e^{-1/z+z}$)